# Is there a way to automatically alphabetize the Quick Launch menu?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, quick-launch, sorting

We're running SharePoint Foundation 2010. I have a Quick Launch list, and I'm constantly going in to re-order it manually as I delete and add itms to keep it relevant. Is there a way to set this up so that new entries automatically alphabetize as items are added and deleted from the list?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing out of the box.  You could possibly do this through jQuery though or some type of timer job that will detect navigation changes and reorder them for you.  I don't think there is an event to key on so it would probably be a polling type thing.  Best performance would be to create a SPChangeQuery to determine if there were any navigation changes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spchangequery.navigation

Answer (score 1):

You can only **manually** (NO OOTB) change the order in which headings or links appear on the Quick Launch, or else you can use some jQuery **customizations** to do such thing:

- Site actions -> Site settings.
- In the Look and Feel column, click Quick launch.
- Click Change Order.
- Click the options in the lists to change the order in which the
  headings and links are displayed. Click OK

Comment: If publishing feature is enabled or you have this option available OOTB but Publishing Feature is not available in Foundation See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/customize-navigation-links-on-the-quick-launch-HA010255192.aspx#BM10